# Angular eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

Angular highlighing stopped working.(For example I get undefined attribute ng-app).  Before I had an option under configure to convert the project to an angular project, but that option is now missing.

I tried reinstalling angular plugin, I even updated to luna but I lost any angular capabilities.

Comment: Have you angular completion? If yes, you must configure Validator https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started#validation

Answer (score 0):

Great light `angular.js` in `webstorm` with `angular plugin`, the better ispolzuite it and I think You will like it.
Оtherwise with eclipse try Eclipse AngularJS Plugin Configuration

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2ulCdYz-zM
```

or

```
http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/using-angularjs-in-eclipse-part-3-wire.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse seems to be falling behind when it comes to writing angular code. I had issues trying to get a legitimate plugin for es6 as well. If you're willing to try out a new editor, you might want to consider intelliJ IDEA which will also allow you to write easily in Java or Spring.

If you're just writing angular, with no server side needs, vs code is free, lightweight, and incredibly handy. Before acquiring a license for intelliJ, I just opened up the angular part of my application in vs code and edited it there. You can even download angular "snippets" to scaffold common structures like controllers or routes for you.